# How to build react-native application with react-native cli?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-cli

I would wish to submit my react-native app to app store, but I don't know how to build it.

I've been following this official doc of react-native (http://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#building-your-app-for-production) about how to build my app for production, but sadly in my case it does not quite give enough information.

Regarding building an app, the guide says this:

> You can now build your app for release by tapping ⌘B or selecting Product → Build from the menu bar. Once built for release, you'll be able to distribute the app to beta testers and submit the app to the App Store.

And I can do this. But the problem is, that I need to build my app with an ENVFILE environment variable that defines where my applications configurations are read from.

With this in mind, the official guide also states:

> You can also use the React Native CLI to perform this operation using the option --configuration with the value Release (e.g. npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release).

This is almost what I want. But I don't want to run my app. I just want to build it. So is there a way to build my app with the react-native cli tool? Without running it? Or could I just run it and in the process it gets build and I could find the final build in some folder then? Or if this doesn't work, could I then some way configure the ENVFILE environment variable to xcode that my app will get it?

Comment: Are you using any packages for ENVFILE ? something like https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config?

Comment: Yes Im using exactly that library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The react-native-config library build can be setup like below.

Step 1 : Create a scheme for the project you can also use the existing ones

Step 2 : Go to edit scheme and chose pre-action under build from left menu
[image]

Step 3 : Provide `echo '.env.yourenvironment' > /tmp/envfile` in the script to run

This will run the script in the post build and copy the values to tmpfile which will be used by the library.

Then you can normally archive or build the project using the scheme you created.

You can check these steps in the [docs](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#ios-1) of the library as well.

Comment: Thx for help. Tried this and got following error while building with xcode: /ReactNativeConfig/BuildDotenvConfig.ruby:39:in `+': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
 from ./ReactNativeConfig/BuildDotenvConfig.ruby:39:in `<main>'
Reading env from env.production
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code. 

My react-native-config seems to be pretty old version: 0.11.1.

Comment: can you try deleting the env file 'rm /tmp/envfile', i've been using this library for a long time and it has been stable

Comment: does the app run in the simulator and set the config properly ? also can i know your RN version so that i can try it out ?

Comment: Got it working now! I can accept your answer if you change Step 3: Provide echo 'env.yourenvironment' -> '.env.yourenvironment'. One dot missing :D